# create Model class to parse without any library

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, model

I want to create a model class for the json.
My JSON example is given below

json response from API:

msg = '{"type":"TYPE_NM","payload":{"responseCode":0,"nextCheckTime":30}}';

I want to create a codable(Swift) properties is like in Objective-C.

I have created two nsobject interfaces as "type" and "payload". Below I am giving my class snippets.

```
      //msg model 
      @interface MessageModel : NSObject

      @property (nonatomic) NSString *type;
      @property (nonatomic) Payload *payload;
      @end
      //for payload
      @interface Payload : NSObject

      @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger responseCode;
      @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger nextCheckTime;

     @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert json string to `NSDictionary` object and use it to create `MessageModel`

***Payload***

```
@interface Payload : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger responseCode;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger nextCheckTime;

@end

@implementation Payload

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    _responseCode = [dict[@"responseCode"] integerValue];
    _nextCheckTime = [dict[@"nextCheckTime"] integerValue];
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

***MessageModel***

```
@interface MessageModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic) Payload *payload;
@end

@implementation MessageModel

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    _type = dict[@"type"];
    _payload = [[Payload alloc] initWithDictionary:dict[@"payload"]];
  }

  return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithJson:(NSString *)json {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    NSData *data = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    _type = dict[@"type"];
    _payload = [[Payload alloc] initWithDictionary:dict[@"payload"]];
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

***Usage***

```
NSString *input = @"{\"type\":\"TYPE_NM\",\"payload\":{\"responseCode\":0,\"nextCheckTime\":30}}";
MessageModel *model = [[MessageModel alloc] initWithJsonString:input];
```